# How to know file name from a pipeline of commands

Tags: bash

I search for some text in some file list. I have the following command to print these lines:

```
ls -1 *.log | xargs tail --lines=10000 | grep text_for_search
```

The command output contains all of occurrences of `text_for_search`, but it hasn't information from which file the occurrences are. How to modify the command to provide this information too?

---

Actually log files are gigabytes in size, so it's essential to use `tail --lines=10000` for each of them

Answer (score 2):

You could just use a loop instead, which will keep track of the file name for you:

```
for file in *.log; do 
    if tail --lines=-10000 "$file" | grep -q text_for_search; then
        echo "$file"
    fi
done
```

The `-q` switch to grep suppresses the output, returning a 0 (success) exit code if the pattern is matched.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `find` command:

```
find . -name "*.log" -exec grep text_for_search '{}' \;
```

grep will output filename and matched line. If you just need filenames - add -l switch to grep command.

`'{}'` - macro used for matched file name substitution in find's -exec command,
`\;` indicates end of arguments for command, called by exec

Comment: don't forget to specify a maxdepth, to replicate the original behaviour

Answer (score 1):

You must avoid parsing `ls` output and use shell's `for` loop to iterate through all `*.log` files:

```
for f in *.log; do
  awk -v c=$(wc -l < "$f") 'NR>c-10000 && /text_for_search/{print FILENAME ":" $0}' "$f"
done
```

---

**EDIT:**

You can use `awk` to search through all `*.log` files:

```
awk 'NR>=10000 && /text_for_search/ {print FILENAME ":" $0}' *.log
```

Comment: Nice use of awk. I always forget how the negative numbers work with head and tail. I guess you can also remove the loop entirely using this approach and just use `*.log` on the awk line too.

Comment: Thanks @TomFenech: I added it in my answer. This minus/plus is really confusing for me and requirers me to read `man tail` every time :)

Comment: Are you sure this works. OP wants to search in last 10000 lines of the file but your command seraches all the lines after the line number is >=10000.

Comment: @Vijay: You are right. OP earlier had `--lines=-10000` and then edited it to `--lines=10000` so I got confused with line number requirement. I wrote a comment as well about this confusion above. In any case it is fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your tail command with:

```
awk '{v[NR]=$0}END{for(i=NR-10000;i<=NR;i++)print FILENAME,v[i]}'
```

This above is just the replacement of the tail command  except it adds a file name in the begining of each line.